# How exactly work?

Tags: python, numpy, random, reshape

When I run this, code it works as expected and gives me 10 images with dimensions of 100x100:

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(10):
    im = np.random.random_integers(0, 255, 10000).reshape((100, 100))
    misc.imsave('random_%03d.png' % i, im)
```

But if I change the arguments to reshape to (200, 200), I recieve an error:

`ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Why does this happen? Why wasn't a 200x200 image returned?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you just want to create a random width-by-height image you could simply use the  `size=` option, instead of reshaping: `im = np.random.random_integers(0, 255, size=(height, width))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am learning whats exactly is happening here it for really understood the code! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reshape 10000 points into 100x100, you cannot reshape 10000 points into 200x200. It is simple math. You'd have to change your call to

```
im = np.random.random_integers(0, 255, 40000).reshape((200, 200))
```

Note you are now sampling 40000 (200*200) points instead of 10000 (100*100)

Comment: Perfect Thank for the answer! now i understand what it is happening!

Comment: @NicoCarosio welcome to stack overflow. be sure to up vote questions you find helpful and to accept (with the green checkmark) the answer that best solves your problem.